# Create a table from the frequencies of taxa found in multiple CSV files

Tags: python, bash, shell, csv, bioinformatics

I have 12 `.csv` files containing fetched taxonomic name and their frequencies (number of times each name was fetched). I've created a master `.txt` file listing all the unique taxa found at least once across the 12 files. I need to make a concatenated table in `csv` format where the headers of the rows are the name of each file, and the headers of the columns are all the unique taxa listed in the master `.txt` file. The table has to be populated with the frequencies next to each taxa in each `.csv` input file. Although the master list contains all taxa possible in the 12 files, not all files contain all the taxa. When the taxa is missing I need to place a '0'.

`.csv` input:

```
$cat file_1

1,Salmo salar
12,Solanum pennellii
18,Staphylococcus xylosus
...

$cat file_2

1,Salmo salar
14,Staphylococcus xylosus
123,Strongyloides stercoralis
...

$cat file_3

123,Solanum pennellii
11,Staphylococcus xylosus
41,Strongyloides stercoralis
...
```

`.txt` master list:

```
$cat master

Salmo salar
Solanum pennellii
Staphylococcus xylosus
Strongyloides stercoralis
...
```

`.csv` output (what I need):

```
Sample,Salmo salar,Solanum pennellii,Staphylococcus xylosus,Strongyloides stercoralis
File_1,1,12,18,0    
File_2,1,0,14,123    
File_3,0,123,11,41
```

I previously tried making a small python script without a master list and using `.tsv` input files containing repeated names of taxa instead of frequencies. I wasn't able to obtain a table that showed missing taxa for each file, so I decided to create a master list and collapse the input files. I am very new at python, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried making a script without using a master list or collapsing the the csv input files (instead of having the frequencies, the file has  the same name repeated several times), but it did not work as I hoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those about to `awk`, we salute you!

`awk` was created for such processing.

Give a try to this:

```
awk -F "," -v OFS="," '
 FNR==1 {samples[++fni]=FILENAME}
 {if (!taxakeys[$2]) {taxakeys[$2]=1; taxas[++ti]=$2};frequencies[samples[fni],$2]+=$1}
 END {
   printf("Sample"); for (j=1;j<=ti;j++) { printf("%s%s",OFS,taxas[j])}; printf("\n") 
   for (i=1; i<=fni; i++) {
     printf("%s",samples[i]); for (j=1;j<=ti;j++) { printf("%s%d",OFS,frequencies[samples[i],taxas[j]])}; printf("\n")
   }
 }'
```

The test:

```
$ awk -F "," -v OFS="," '
 FNR==1 {samples[++fni]=FILENAME}
 {if (!taxakeys[$2]) {taxakeys[$2]=1; taxas[++ti]=$2};frequencies[samples[fni],$2]+=$1}
 END {
   printf("Sample"); for (j=1;j<=ti;j++) { printf("%s%s",OFS,taxas[j])}; printf("\n") 
   for (i=1; i<=fni; i++) {
     printf("%s",samples[i]); for (j=1;j<=ti;j++) { printf("%s%d",OFS,frequencies[samples[i],taxas[j]])}; printf("\n")
   }
 }' file_*

Sample,Salmo salar,Solanum pennellii,Staphylococcus xylosus,Strongyloides stercoralis
file_1,1,12,18,0
file_2,1,0,14,123
file_3,0,123,11,41
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the master file at all.  I'd just generate the final table dynamically.  Assuming you pass the input filenames as command line arguments to your Python script:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(dict) # { taxon: { filename: count } }                                                               

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            count, taxon = line.rstrip().split(',')
            data[taxon][filename] = count
```

Now you have `data` which is everything you need for your output file.  You can then print it like this:

```
taxa = data.keys()
print "Sample,{}".format(','.join(taxa))
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    print filename,
    for taxon in taxa:
        count = data[taxon].get(filename, "0")
        sys.stdout.write("," + count)
    print
```

Comment: Would I be able to call it as `python xyz.py file_1 file_2 file_3` in the shell? (I already know I have the current and previous version of python installed).

Comment: @LuciaO: Yes, that is how you would invoke it.

Comment: It seems that when it gets to `print "Sample,{}".format(','.join(taxa))` it has no information to print. Also, how is the script creating an output file? I don't entirely follow that step, (sorry, I am very new at python).

Answer (score 0):

Try using **csv.Dictwriter**.

1. Read in the 12 files you have into a dictionary of the format filename = {species_name: count, species_name:count}.
2. Read in the master_list txt file into a list
3. Use the csv.Dictwriter which will write a csv file from the dictionaries you have created. You can specify it to put a 0 in case there is no data for a species in a file. You headers will be the list of species from master_list.